# listview with switch does not work

Tags: android, listview

I have an activity, that contains a listview. (it utilizes a custom adapter, lets say adap1)

I also have a switch,

```
 <Switch
        android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="on/off" />
```

it is initialized as follows :

```
Switch switch1; //global
switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch); //inside onCreate()
if (switch1 != null) 
{
    switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}
else
{
    Log.i(tag, "switch1 is null");
}
```

which, upon click, the listview changes (the new one utilizes another custom adapter, with different layout, and views, lets say Adap2). Adap2 has a checkbox as one of its view in the row.

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
{
      if(isChecked)
      {
            adapter1 = new Adap1 (this, al);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter1);        
      }
      else
      {     
            adapter2 = new Adap2 (this, al);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter2);
      }
}
```

And then I call this in my onCreate();

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                if(switch1.isChecked())
                {               
                    Log.i(tag, "Switch is checked");
                }
                  else
                      {             
                        Log.i(tag, "Switch is not checked");
                      }
```

However, "Switch is checked" never gets shown.

Is it because I am using 2 different custom adapters each with different XMLs and the code does not know which View I am using ?

Comment: What is a switch toggle? Do you mean a `ToggleButton`? Where in the layout is it located?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. As far as I can see the custom adapter switching is not related to this problem. Can you provide more details about how the switch is initialized?

Comment: @Nachi, I should also note that the adap2 has a CHECKBOX view in row.